# How to change the App.xcframework name of flutter module

Tags: ios, flutter

I have created a flutter module and after running `flutter build ios-framework` it generates `App.xcframework` and `Flutter.xcframework`

How can I specify to something else like `MyFlutter.xcframework` instead of `App.xcframework` for my framework